# Python os.environ["HOME"] works on idle but not in a script

Tags: python, python-2.7, cmd

I am working on a simple Python (2.7.3) script, but I have to get the user's Home Folder.
I tried:

```
import os
home_folder = os.environ["HOME"]
```

And it works fine when I'm running this code on IDLE, but if I launch it from the cmd, it gives me: `«KeyError: 'HOME'»`

Can someone tell me why? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What environment are you running the script in? Linux, Windows, cron?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Windows uses `USERPROFILE`, instead of `HOME`. Windows doesn't have `HOME` and other OSs don't have `USERPROFILE`, so using either of these drops platform independence.

To keep platform independence, you can use `expanduser` from `os.path`, like so:

```
import os.path
home_folder = os.path.expanduser('~')
```

On a side note, you can use `print(os.environ)` to see all the environment variables you to have access to, which shows that `IDLE` has extras.

Comment: Thanks! It really confused me, that's why I asked it here.

Answer (score 6):

Windows has no HOME environment variable. It uses USERPROFILE instead. 
To solve the problem you can define a new variable "HOME" typing on your console:

```
set HOME=%USERPROFILE%
```

as a copy of the USERPROFILE variable.

You can check that they are identical typing:

```
echo %USERPROFILE%
echo %HOME%
```

It will work for the current session.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're trying to run this on Windows based entirely on your "[launching] it from the cmd". IDLE is giving you that as a convenience; on Windows use `USERPROFILE` instead of `HOME`. The `%USERPROFILE%` envar is the Win32 `$HOME`.