# How to run git fetch over ssh in a windows subprocess

Tags: python, windows, git, github, ssh

I've got some code which needs to grab code from github periodically (on a Windows machine).

When I do pulls manually, I use GitBash, and I've got ssh keys running for the repos I check so everything is fine. However when I try to run the same actions in a python subprocess I don't have the ssh services which GitBash provides and I'm unable to authenticate to the repo.

How should I proceed from here. I can think of a couple of different options:

1. I could revert to using https:// fetches. This is problematic because the repos I'm fetching use 2-factor authentication and are going to be running unattended.  Is there a way to access an https repo that has 2fa from a command line?
2. I've tried calling sh.exe with arguments that will fire off ssh-agent and then issuing my commands so that everything is running more or less the way it does in gitBash, but that doesn't seem to work:

   ```
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe"  -c "C:/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Git/bin/ssh-agent.exe; C:/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Git/bin/ssh.exe -t git@github.com"
   ```

   produces

   ```
   SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-SiVYsy3660/agent.3660; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
   SSH_AGENT_PID=8292; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
   echo Agent pid 8292;
   Could not create directory '/.ssh'.
   The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.252.129)' can't be established.
   RSA key fingerprint is XXXXXXXXXXX
   Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
   Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/.ssh/known_hosts).
   Permission denied (publickey).
   ```
3. Could I use an ssh module in python like `paramiko` to establish a connection? It looks to me like that's only for ssh'ing into a remote terminal. Is there a way to make it provide an ssh connection that git.exe can use?

So, I'd be grateful if anybody has done this before or has a better alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The git bash set the `HOME` environment variable, which allows git to find the ssh keys (in `%HOME%/.ssh`)

You need to make sure the python process has or define HOME to the same PATH.
As explained in "[Python `os.environ[“HOME”]` works on idle but not in a script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14742225/6309)", you need to set `HOME` to `%USERPROFILE%` (or, in python, to `os.path.expanduser("~")` ).

Comment: That did it, thanks!  Setting the HOME variable correctly got it running